# I/flutter : No camera is found

Tags: flutter, camera

I have no error message in my code for the camera.

The permission has been granted to use the caemera for the apps.

However, I reveice the following messages with NO CAMERA IS FOUND.

> I/flutter (12856): Model Response: Instance of 'Future'
> I/tflite  (12856): Replacing 31 node(s) with delegate >(TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 1 partitions.>
> I/flutter (12856): No camera is found

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

typedef void Callback(List<dynamic> list, int h, int w);

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  final Callback setRecognitions;

  const Camera({this.cameras, this.setRecognitions});

  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  bool isDetecting = false;

  static const platform = const MethodChannel('ondeviceML');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras.length < 1) {
      print('No camera is found');
    } else {
      controller = new CameraController(
        // widget.camera[0] for back camera
        // widget.camera[1] for front camera
        widget.cameras[1],
        ResolutionPreset.high,
      );

      controller.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});

        controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
          if (!isDetecting) {
            isDetecting = true;

            int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

            Tflite.runPoseNetOnFrame(
              bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
                return plane.bytes;
              }).toList(),
              imageHeight: img.height,
              imageWidth: img.width,
              numResults: 1,
              rotation: -90,
              threshold: 0.2,
              nmsRadius: 10,
            ).then((recognitions) {
              int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
              print("Detection took ${endTime - startTime}");

              widget.setRecognitions(recognitions, img.height, img.width);

              isDetecting = false;
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    var tmp = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var screenH = math.max(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var screenW = math.min(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    tmp = controller.value.previewSize;
    var previewH = math.max(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var previewW = math.min(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var screenRatio = screenH / screenW;
    var previewRatio = previewH / previewW;

    return OverflowBox(
      maxHeight:
          screenRatio > previewRatio ? screenH : screenW / previewW * previewH,
      maxWidth:
          screenRatio > previewRatio ? screenH / previewH * previewW : screenW,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On which platform do you run the app? Can you please paste some code?

Comment: @CodeMaster, I added the codes for the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the conditions

```
if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras.length < 1) {
  print('No camera is found');
} else {
```

then ensure cameras was passed on from main.dart to all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras.length < 1) {
      print('No camera is found');
}
```

Try writing this instead:

```
if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras.isEmpty) {
      print('No camera is found');
}
```

But if widget.cameras can be null, you have to make it nullable:

```
class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription>? cameras; // Add question mark
  final Callback setRecognitions;

  const Camera({this.cameras, this.setRecognitions});

  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}
```

Comment: Hi, good suggestion, but I receive this error message Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty)

Comment: I edited my answer, please try it out.

Comment: Same result with NO CAMERA IS FOUND, I think the issue is from the widget etc..

Comment: I found the solution - thanks for contributing